# How do I use CSS with simple form?

Tags: css, simple-form

I have a text_area that is showing up with a height that is too large.

I am using simple form and I have read their documentation, but am still unclear on how to apply a css class to a text_area.

My form:

```
  <div class="field">
    <p>What's on your mind?</p>
    <%= f.text_area :content, :wrapper_html => { :class => 'height-100px' }, placeholder: "Thought leads to action..." %>
  </div>
```

My css:

```
.height-100px {
   height:100px;
}
```

When I apply CSS to a div surrounding the input field it truncates the height, but inserts a scrollbar. Clearly, I am not applying the right css in that case.

I think this is an easy question to answer, but let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Hey David, apologies, but I don't know what you mean. I'm trying to apply a class to a form element in rails/simple_form. I am not tied to using ruby or rails to apply the class name, but that seems to be the best practice from all I've read. Is the question unclear or am I not understanding?

Comment: No; I mis-read the question (or misunderstood the *intent*). Sorry for the confusion! =)

Comment: Probably the way I worded it. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up applying the class name "mf" to the section and using the generic "textarea" element to style all textareas on the site using this:

```
.mf {
textarea { 
height:50px;
}
}
```

Would have been nice to apply the class name directly on the simpleform element, but it would not work for me...